# Delaying the loading spinner while doing ajax requests in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the following mockup to show my loading spinner while doing AJAX requests in my jQuery code:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function() {
    $('#loader').show()
},
complete: function(){
    $('#loader').hide()
},
success: function() {
    $('#loader').hide()
}
});
```

This code works perfectly fine for me!

**Just one problem:**

Some requests are just very simple and fast, so the loading spinner is just shown for a couple of millisecs. That of course isn't very pretty.

So I tried using `setTimeout()` to display the loading spinner slightly delayed. I want it to only pop up if the AJAX requests takes at least, let's say 100ms, but it didn't work.

So I need some code to delay the loading spinner as I explained above, so it ONLY pops up while doing "longer" AJAX requests!

Comment: When you say "but it didn't work" what didn't work? Can you show us the code you tried?

Answer (score 11):

This is how I resolved your mentioned functionality

```
    var loading;
    $("#loader").hide();
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function() {
             loading= setTimeout("$('#loader').show()", 300);
        },
        complete: function(){
             clearTimeout(loading);
             $("#loader").hide();   
        },
        success: function() {
             alert("done");
        }
    });
```

Comment: This will present the same problem if the request takes 301 ms to complete.  Except worse, since now the user has to wait a while with nothing apparently happening before it shows.

Comment: I suppose a bit of preference.  If you do not know how long your request will take, I think it is safer to say: hold out on showing the loader until the request falls past a fast load threshold

Comment: Doesn't work at 100%! :(
Problem is now that the loading spinner is also shown when loading the page the first time and doesn't disappear afterwards.

I tried using $('#loader').hide() @ document.ready but still doesnt disappear after loading the page successfully!

Comment: See edits.  Initially, there is no reason reason for the spinner to be visible if you are hiding it on load. All subsequent ajax calls should use the defined options. Maybe you have more to include?

Comment: This won't work if you have multiple AJAX calls in parallel, right? Do you know how to best circumvent this?

Comment: For many ajax requests/callbacks, I would probably manage them with jQuery.Deferred() http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but I've found a much nicer and elegant approach.  jQuery exposes a variable `$.active` which is the number of currently active ajax requests.  The value of this increases before `ajaxSend` and decreases after `ajaxComplete`.

With that in mind, all we need to do is show the spinner when `ajaxSend` is fired and `$.active == '1'` and hide the spinner when `ajaxComplete` is fired and `$.active == '1'`.  Here's my code which is currently working flawlessly.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
    $.active == '1' ? $('#spinner').show() : '';
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
    $.active == '1' ? $('#spinner').hide() : '';
});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Common solution I've seen to this is to keep the throbber up for a second or two, even if the request finishes faster than that.  Something like:

```
var loaded = false;
var throbbed = false;

function checkComplete(){
    if(loaded && throbbed){
        $("#loader").hide();
    }
}

function requestComplete(){
    loaded = true;
    checkComplete();
}

jQuery.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function() {
    $('#loader').show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        throbbed = true;
        checkComplete();
    }, 500);

},
complete: requestComplete,
success: requestComplete
});
```

Obviously this has a tradeoff of making things slower at the expense of looking pretty, so it's case-dependent whether you want to take that hit or not.  If it's something that gets used all the time, you're probably better off accepting the ugly.  If it's something that happens every once and a while, users won't notice an extra 500 mils.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var timeout;

jQuery.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function() {
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        timeout = null;
        $('#loader').show();
    }, 100);
},
complete: function(){
    if (timeout) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    }
    $('#loader').hide()
},
success: function() {
    // No need to do anything here since complete always will be called
}
});
```

Now you need to improve this a bit if you are firing several request at the same time, but hopefully you get the picture.

Comment: Doesn't work at 100%! :(
Problem is now that the loading spinner is also shown when loading the page the first time and doesn't disappear afterwards.

I tried using $('#loader').hide() @ document.ready but still doesnt disappear after loading the page successfully!

Answer (score 0):

Reply now because I encounter the same problem and these answers give me  part of solution.
To avoid start spinner after the ajax request is complete becouse time of timeout is wider than execution script you need a up/down flag check, is very simple and is work for me.

```
var m = $('.modal-ajax');
var run = false; // global scope is necessary
m.hide(); // if isn't hidden in css

jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
        run = true; // up flag          
        d = setTimeout(function(){
            if(run) // is ajax executing now?
                m.show();
        },100); // is trigged only for NO fast response
    },
    complete: function(){
        m.hide();
        run = false; // down flag                
    },
    success: function() {            
  //  do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to this thread, but thought this might be helpful.  Bootstrap v4.4.1 is currently used in my app.  I have a modal spinner defined as follows:

```
<div class="modal-spinner modal fade" id="loadingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered justify-content-center" role="document">
            <div role="status" style="width: 48px">
                <span class="fa-solid fa-spinner fa-spin fa-4x"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I've noticed is the "fade" class in the initial DIV causes the modal to not disappear when it's a fast-running process as noted by the original poster.  It's possible to alter the Bootstrap fade class to be a smaller transition time, but that didn't always work for me either.  The combination of .ajaxSend, .ajaxComplete, .ajaxStop wasn't consistent either.  The only thing that was consistent was removal of the fade class.

Hope that helps.....